# Постинг URL как аттачмент в VK.com и переменная cur. Как?

Tags: javascript, вконтакте

Пытаюсь отправить сообщение в ВК, в которой есть ссылка через cURL. Но ссылка таким образом не обрабатывается в картинку с описанием (например, ссылка на игру в Google Play). После того, как немного разобрался было выяснено, что ссылка в теле сообщения обрабатывается ДО отправки сообщения. Таким образом, ссылка уже прикрепляется к сообщению в виде так называемого `media`. ВК первым делом делает такой запрос (в виде формы это будет выглядеть так):

```
<form action="https://vk.com/share.php?act=url_attachment" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="hash" value="1483521930_4df3bf64c61e553f1a">
<input type="hidden" name="allowed_share_buttons" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="index" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://ссылка.ком">
<input type="hidden" name="to_mail" value="">
</form>
```

На первый взгляд кажется все просто. Но откуда берется значение параметра `hash` (в js-скриптах ВК она же берется из `cur.share_timehash`)? Без него прикрепление ссылки к сообщению не произойдет.

*Прикрепление ссылки к сообщению:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*А вот что происходит:*

[image: Веб-консоль Chrome]

Comment: А как cURL и `vk.com/share.php` связаны? Это же адрес для социального шаринга. Что за переменные `hash` и `cur.share_timehash`? Из вашего вопроса ровным счетом ничего не понятно, сформулируйте его понятнее и предоставьте весь код, включая запросы на cURL и ваш JavaScript.

Comment: Позже добавлю больше информации и кода. Пока поясню, что я делаю. Я пытаюсь с помощью РНР отправить комментарий в которой есть ссылка. Нужно, чтобы ссылка была обработана соц.сетью и выводилась ссылка, которая включает в себя картинку с описанием. Как это происходит можно увидеть при помощи консоли веб-разработчика в Chrome во вкладке Network. Сначала идет запрос на `https://vk.com/share.php?act=url_attachment`, затем еще 2 переадресации `302`

Comment: Я вас понял. На самом деле, едва ли изобретение такого велосипеда поможет. У меня, например, через консоль прекрасно публикуются ссылки с превьюшками и описанием, а вот через прямой вызов API почему-то ссылка не обрабатывается и крепится "некрасиво". Также через консоль ссылка крепится красиво только в том случае, если она идет первой в параметре `attachments`. Короче, надо разбираться. Подпишусь на ваш вопрос, самому любопытно.

Comment: Я соорудил свою задумку на JS. К сожалению, такое провернуть на РНР вряд ли удастся, поскольку нужные для запроса параметры генерируются на клиентской части.

Comment: @Trancer один мой знакомый не может написать на SO из-за недостатка репутации, но очень заинтересован вашим решением. возможно ли как-то связаться напрямую?